# Зависает терминал

Tags: javascript

После вода команды node main.js терминал зависает . Делаю я её в VS Code

```
const { Client, Intents} = require (`discord.js`) ;
const { token } = require(`./config.json`) ;

const client = new Client ({ intents: [32767]});

const prefix = `!`

client.once(`ready`, () => {
    console.log(`Ready!`);
});

client.on(`massage`, massage => {
    if(!massage.content.startsWith(prefix)  || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = massage.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === `ping`) {
        massage.channel.send(`pong!`);
    }
})


client.login(token) ;
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что "сообщение" на английском будет "mAssage"?

Comment: Изменено на message , но всё равно не работает . 

client.on("message", message => { 
    if(message.content.toLowerCase()==config.prefix + "ping") 
    {
    message.reply("мой пинг равен " + client.ping)
    }
    
})

Comment: В консоле отладки нечего не показывается (если туда не надо нечего водить) если вы не про эту консоль , то про какую ?

Comment: @user523590 терминал не зависает - там выполняется процесс, в котором ваш сервер слушает сообщения и обрабатывает их в стрелочной функции 
message => {}.

отправьте сообщение и посмотрите что выведется в терминале!

Comment: @user523590 сообщение - "Ready!" выводится в терминал?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139869/discussion-between-jackson-and-nl993).

Comment: "Ready!" выводится , но дальше терминал перестаёт принимать команды

Comment: а какие команды и откуда вы ожидаете??

поменяйте обработчик on message на вот этот с ссылки:
https://jsfiddle.net/hs9oz6ab/

Comment: посмотрите файл config.js - куда вы там коннектитесь - зайдите в дискорд и отправьте там сообщение, и посмотрите что будет в терминале